# React Multiple Text Inputs Controlling Each Other State

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, components, setstate

[Working CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/62331l6z5k)

So I'm learning to use React, and trying to create a currency exchange app.
I'm having a problem understanding how to `setState` from multiple inputs depending on the input you're actually using.

I set up a CodePen to show you what I'm trying to do.

Things I know or don't:

1. Right now I'm only updating a `tempValue` state.
2. If I use the first input field it gives me the desired effect.

   2.1 I know in this case I'm not updating the states, I'm just doing my math right on the value prop (but it works to show my intention).

   2.2 I don't know if I should do the math on `setState` or on a separate method.

   2.3 I can probably use a wait timer and look for onKeyDown then `setState`.
3. I could probably use uncontrolled components, but it wouldn't be the React way (is it a bad thing).
4. My `setState` originally used [computed properties] for the name but changed it for demonstration purposes.

[Working CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/62331l6z5k)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to the input in your onChange function, you can get the input name off `event.target` and use that to make modifications in your state.

Alternatively you can bind the function:

```
<CurrencyInput
    onChange={this.handleCurrencyInput.bind(this, currency.name)}
/>
```

But this isn't the best to do in your render, so you could make a `renderCurrencyInput` method on your class and bind once there

Computed properties would work, I don't see much of an issue with it. Then you can drive your initial `this.state` from your list of currencies